# Returning two user define type object from stored procedure and calling stored procedure at repository level using spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a stored procedure as define follows:

```
PROCEDURE TestABC (tableName IN VARCHAR2, cardID IN VARCHAR2, detail OUT UserDefineObjectA, td OUT UserDefineObjectB);
```

`UserDefineObjectA` , `UserDefineObjectB` both are user defined Object and both have same fields and I am excepting both object should return from the procedure. There is some business behind to return the both objects.

I wrote method class with `@Repository` annotation which has following method. I am using `@Procedure` annotation from `spring-data -jpa`. The current implementation `@Procedure` can take only one `outputParameterName`. But for my case, I am excepting to return two user define type object.

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "TestABC" , outputParameterName = "{UserDefineObjectA, UserDefineObjectB}")
public List<Object[]> getAllDetails(@Param("tableName") String tableName, @Param("cardID ") String cardID);
```

Then, I tried different approaches using `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`. But the problem is with this approach is I have to write all those query to Entity label which add more complexity. I have to create a Entity and wrote all stored procedure and call to the repository as below example:

[how to get user-defined SQL procedure out parameter from java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580884/how-to-get-userdefined-sql-procedure-out-parameter-from-java-class)

Is there any better way I can solve this problem? Can I write `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` at method level inside my class which is annotated as `@Repository`.

The legacy code example which I am trying to implement.

```
    callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call ABC(?,?,?,?)}");

      callableStatement.setString(1, "test");
      callableStatement.setString(2, "12345679090978");

      callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY, AConstants.UserDefineObjectA);
      callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.STRUCT, AConstants.UserDefineObjectB);

      callableStatement.execute();
      return (Object[]) ((java.sql.Array) callableStatement.getObject(3)).getArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is **two ways** you can settle this.

**1.Update Spring Data JPA Version**

Multiple out parameters is supported since Spring Data JPA 2.2-RC1.
https://spring.io/blog/2019/06/17/spring-data-moore-rc1-and-lovelace-sr9-released
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-707

The interface method just needs to have a Map return type so each out param can be accessed by key name:

```
/**
 * Explicitly mapped to named stored procedure "User.plus1IOoptional" in {@link EntityManager}. 
 * Returns 2 out params
 * as a Map, second one amoung which is null.
*/
@Procedure(name = "User.plus1IOoptional") // DATAJPA-1579
Map<String, Integer> entityAnnotatedCustomNamedProcedurePlus1IOoptional(@Param("arg") Integer arg);
```

[More samples on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/e27933455efa6d1821dea23abd2bbe109b5d59a7/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java)

**2.Use the JPA API directly, through a little more complicated**

```
StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("plus1");

proc.setParameter("arg", 1);
proc.execute();
Integer res1 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("res1");
Integer res2 = (Integer) proc.getOutputParameterValue("res2");
```

I hope it would help.

Comment: So, I have to return a type as  Map. But My store procedure is excepting 4 fields as input. Is there will be any issue? I am excepting the Map type which can be accessed by key name. Updated my old legacy code which i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your legacy code seems  to use the JDCB to call the procedure.<br>Well I would prefer using jpa directroy.